# Не закрывает клавиатуру по нажатию return/ввод ios

Tags: ios, swift

```
 import UIKit

class RecoveryPasswordViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var PhoneRecoveryTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ErrorLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var SendPasswordButton: UIButton!
var dataStringJSon:String?

@IBAction func sendPassword(_ sender: Any) {


}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch!{
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    PhoneRecoveryTextField.delegate=self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing()
    return true
}
```